# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: channel is a required argument that is missing. пишу +join выводит то что в заголовке

Tags: python, discord

Столкнулся с проблемой после ввода +join пишет
`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: channel is a required argument that is missing`

```
I am connected!
Ignoring exception in command join:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 706, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\alexe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: channel is a required argument that is missing.
```

[Полный код](https://pastebin.com/i540CfGJ)

Answer (score 0):

Роман. Твоя ошибка здесь :

```
@commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
        """Joins a voice channel"""
 
        if ctx.voice_client is not None:
            return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)
 
        await channel.connect()
```

Потому что ты не подставил значение channel, а просто сказал ему что это голосовой канал, вместо этого используй :

```
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
```

заметь , что пользователь должен быть подключен к какому-либо голосовому каналу и бот подключится к нему.